# JQuery post with MVC error

Tags: jquery, post

I am using a JQuery in an MVC appliaction post that is erroring out, is there someway to tell what the error is?

Example code -

```
    $.post("/Path/Action", form, function (returnHtml) {

        //do stuff

    }).error(function () { alert("error"); });
```

I have attached the ".error" call but that doesn't tell me the cause of the error.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you look at the arguments in the function?

Comment: You mean the "returnHtml"?  I put an alert in the "//do stuff" section, but it never make it in there.

Comment: No in the function in the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.error( function (jqXHR, status, error) {
    alert(jqXHR);
    alert(status),
    alert(error);
 })
```

Comment: Thanks user1026361! I used your answer.

Comment: No Problem!  I took the answer straight from jquery.com which is an excellent resource for this library!

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({  
    type: 'POST',  
    url: '/Path/Action',  
    data: form,  
    success: function (data) {  
        console.debug(data);  
    },  
    error: function (data) {  
        console.debug(data);  
    }  
});
```

Comment: That is one way to make the call, but not what the OP asked for.

Comment: Thanks webdeveloper! I will probably use your style of call in the future!

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you debugged it on your own based on my comment, but you can get the info this way

```
$.post("/error/").error( function(xhrObject,statusName,statusText) {
    console.log(xhrObject,statusName,statusText);  //Passed in info via arguments
    console.log(xhrObject.status);  //get the status code via the xhr object
});​
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vxYUm/)

Comment: I used user1026361's solution, but Thanks epascarello!